# Drop Shadow Effect not Showing [CSS3, Twitter Bootstrap 3]

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, dropshadow

I'm trying to install a fancy box-shadow effect. Here's the code I'm using (it's the code I've found on almost all sources):

```
.effect2
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect2:before, .effect2:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.effect2:after
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap, and my element is structured as following:

```
<div class="row callout effect2">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <h3 class="center">
          You can see some of my designs, and download
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, for some reason the box shadow doesn't show up at all. I've tried other box shadows without the curved effect, and they work. Is this the right way to create a box shadow as shown in effect 2 [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/different-css3-box-shadows-effects)? If not, how do I create it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what about an fiddle?

Comment: Shouldn't need prefixing... http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow

Answer (score 0):

try

```
h3 {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
}
```

and replace

```
.effect2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #FFF;
    margin: 40px auto;
}
```

You can find the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ipmincubus/p7ENz/1/)